# How to visualize two (or more) subnetworks in Netlogo using circle layout

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know if it could be possible to visualize two distinct subnetworks (e.g., made up by turtles white and another one made up by turtles orange) with some links between them.
Visually, they should look like two networks having layout circle (`layout-circle`), for instance.
Currently I can visualize only one network made up by turtles orange and white (to give you an idea: https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photos-people-join-merge-social-two-circles-as-network-business-groups-image30895498).

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

An example of what I am trying to do is shown below.

```
to WS [N k p] 
  create-types1 N [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  create-types2 N [
    set color orange
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  layout-circle sort types1 max-pycor * 0.9

  let lis (n-values (k / 2) [ [i] -> i + 1 ])
  ask types1 [
    let w who
    foreach lis [ [i] -> create-link-with (type1 ((w + i) mod N)) ]
  ]
  rewire p

end

to rewire [p] 
  ask links [
    let rewired? false
    if (random-float 1) < p
    [
      let node1 end1
      if [ count link-neighbors ] of node1 < (count types1 - 1)
      [
        let node2 one-of types1 with [ (self != node1) and (not link-neighbor? node1) ]
        ask node1 [ create-link-with node2 [ set rewired? true ] ]
      ]
    ]
    if (rewired?)
    [
      die
    ]
  ]
end
```

The code above should create a small world network where there are two types of breeds: `type1` and `type2`, distinguished by the color.
Instead of visualizing the types within the same network, I would like to create one small world network for type1 and another one for type2. These two networks would be linked by a few links that there might exist between the two types.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provide your current code, that way we can look to adjust a few lines instead of having to write an example from scratch. (I didn't downvote but can understand it, as we get many questions without any code examples here)

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I agree that would I'd be looking for here is code and a description of what roadblock you encountered in making it work. Is there some fundamental difficulty here? If so, what is it?

Comment: Hi both, I added the code for creating a network. My difficulties are in creating and visualizing two networks, one for type1 and one for type2, instead of showing all the types (using different colors) within the same net. The example shown in the figure should help a bit understand what I would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something along these lines?
I create both circles independently and then move them to their desired position, as well as creating the links separately for both types.

```
breed [types1 type1]
breed [types2 type2]

to WS [N k p] 
  create-types1 N [
    set color white
  ]

  create-types2 N [
    set color orange
  ]

  layout-circle sort types1 max-pycor * 0.5
  ask types1 [setxy xcor - 5.5 ycor]
  
  layout-circle sort types2 max-pycor * 0.5
  ask types2 [setxy xcor + 5.5 ycor]

  let lis (n-values (k / 2) [ [i] -> i + 1 ])
  
  ask types1 [
    let w who
    foreach lis [ [i] -> create-link-with (type1 ((w + i) mod N)) ]
  ]
  
  ;let links1 link-set [my-links] of types1
  
  ask types2 [
    let w who
    foreach lis [ [i] -> create-link-with (type2 ((w + i) mod N + N)) ]
  ]
  
  ;let links2 link-set [my-links] of types2

end
```